# Move element with range directly -javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change with the change of position (range) without cutting
When I change and I raise my hand on the (range) starts the movement
But I want to convey with the change directly

my code with run:

```js
function move(){
 var x = document.getElementById("spin").value;
 var image = document.getElementById("test").style;
 image.marginLeft=x+"px";
}
```

```css
    #test h3{
          margin-left:0px;
      overflow: hidden;
      color:red;
          }
```

```html
   <html>
    <head>
 
      </head>
     <body>
<input type="range" name="spin" id="spin" step="1" value="0" min="0" max="500"  onChange="move()" style="width:100%;"/>
       <div id="test"><h3>I want move with range ):</h3></div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: sorry for my bad English langues .. For this I Attachment run code .. i just want move element with range @DontVoteMeDown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `oninput` instead of `onchange` to change the text postiion in real-time.

```js
function move(){
 var x = document.getElementById("spin").value;
 var image = document.getElementById("test").style;
 image.marginLeft=x+"px";
}
```

```css
#test h3{
          margin-left:0px;
      overflow: hidden;
      color:red;
          }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
 
      </head>
     <body>
<input type="range" name="spin" id="spin" step="1" value="0" min="0" max="500"  oninput="move()" style="width:100%;"/>
       <div id="test"><h3>I want move with range ):</h3></div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: @JackKing happy to help

Answer (score 2):

Change the event listener from `change` to `mousemove`.

For [better animation performance](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/animations/animations-and-performance) use CSS `transform` property.

```js
function move(){
    var x = document.getElementById("spin").value;
    var image = document.getElementById("test");
    image.style.transform = "translateX(" + x + "px)";
}
```

```css
body {
   overflow-x: hidden;
}

#test {
   will-change: transform;
}

#test h3{
   margin-left:0px;
   overflow: hidden;
   color:red;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" name="spin" id="spin" step="1" value="0" min="0" max="500" onmousemove="move()" style="width:100%;"/>
<div id="test"><h3>I want move with range ):</h3></div>
```

Comment: This is also a great
Thank you